# update datebase via javascript confirm AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to get a database update via the javascript confirm() function using AJAX. If the user presses "OK" I want to run "accepted_order.php" and if the user presses "Cancel" I want to run "declined_order.php" **without having to leave the page.**

The code I have now is (I must say that I'm not the biggest expert  AJAX):

```
if (confirm("You got a new order of " + amount + " SEK") == true) {

    xmlhttp.open("GET","accepted_order.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
} else {
   xmlhttp.open("GET","declined_order.php",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

As of now the cormirm box doesn't show up in the browser, without the AJAX code the confirm box does show up.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: So what doesn't work in your script? (Obviously you have a `}` too many) And why did you tag jQuery if you aren't using it?

Comment: The problem is now that the entire confirm doesnt show up when I enter the AJAX code, without the AJAX code the confrim works fine

Comment: show the rest of your ajax code. the problem MUST be before the if statement. Also look to your console for errors.

Comment: please see the comment of Paolo, that worked for my, thanks all for thinking with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the xml http request object first with

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

And remove the extra `}` in your code inside the first `if` block.

This is causing an error before `confirm` is executed.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

if (confirm("You got a new order of " + amount + " SEK") == true) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","accepted_order.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} else {
   xmlhttp.open("GET","declined_order.php",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest to start using the console / developer tools of your browser. You'd spot errors like those very easily and quickly.